# DevExtreme DataGrid with Angular: Remove automated save after edit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devexpress, devextreme

I'm using a dataGrid widget (from DevExtreme lib) for my Angular app.

The dataGrid works well, and any editing actions are automatically saved.

I want to cancel this automated save action and replace it with:

- a simple button which does the SAVE when clicked.

Here is the code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { DxDataGridModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { Customer, Service } from './app.service';

if(!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
    enableProdMode();
}

@Component({
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
    selector: 'demo-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    providers: [Service]
})
export class AppComponent {
    customers: Customer[];

    constructor(service: Service) {
        this.customers =  service.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="customers"
    [columns]="['CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax']">
</dx-data-grid>
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class Customer {
    ID: number;
    CompanyName: string;
    Address: string;
    City: string;
    State: string;
    Zipcode: number;
    Phone: string;
    Fax: string;
    Website: string;
}

let customers: Customer[] = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "CompanyName": "Super Mart of the West",
    "Address": "702 SW 8th Street",
    "City": "Bentonville",
    "State": "Arkansas",
    "Zipcode": 72716,
    "Phone": "(800) 555-2797",
    "Fax": "(800) 555-2171",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitesupermart.com"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "CompanyName": "Electronics Depot",
    "Address": "2455 Paces Ferry Road NW",
    "City": "Atlanta",
    "State": "Georgia",
    "Zipcode": 30339,
    "Phone": "(800) 595-3232",
    "Fax": "(800) 595-3231",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitedepot.com"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "CompanyName": "K&S Music",
    "Address": "1000 Nicllet Mall",
    "City": "Minneapolis",
    "State": "Minnesota",
    "Zipcode": 55403,
    "Phone": "(612) 304-6073",
    "Fax": "(612) 304-6074",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitemusic.com"
}, {
    "ID": 4,
    "CompanyName": "Tom's Club",
    "Address": "999 Lake Drive",
    "City": "Issaquah",
    "State": "Washington",
    "Zipcode": 98027,
    "Phone": "(800) 955-2292",
    "Fax": "(800) 955-2293",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitetomsclub.com"
}, {
    "ID": 5,
    "CompanyName": "E-Mart",
    "Address": "3333 Beverly Rd",
    "City": "Hoffman Estates",
    "State": "Illinois",
    "Zipcode": 60179,
    "Phone": "(847) 286-2500",
    "Fax": "(847) 286-2501",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsiteemart.com"
}, {
    "ID": 6,
    "CompanyName": "Walters",
    "Address": "200 Wilmot Rd",
    "City": "Deerfield",
    "State": "Illinois",
    "Zipcode": 60015,
    "Phone": "(847) 940-2500",
    "Fax": "(847) 940-2501",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitewalters.com"
}, {
    "ID": 7,
    "CompanyName": "StereoShack",
    "Address": "400 Commerce S",
    "City": "Fort Worth",
    "State": "Texas",
    "Zipcode": 76102,
    "Phone": "(817) 820-0741",
    "Fax": "(817) 820-0742",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsiteshack.com"
}, {
    "ID": 8,
    "CompanyName": "Circuit Town",
    "Address": "2200 Kensington Court",
    "City": "Oak Brook",
    "State": "Illinois",
    "Zipcode": 60523,
    "Phone": "(800) 955-2929",
    "Fax": "(800) 955-9392",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitecircuittown.com"
}, {
    "ID": 9,
    "CompanyName": "Premier Buy",
    "Address": "7601 Penn Avenue South",
    "City": "Richfield",
    "State": "Minnesota",
    "Zipcode": 55423,
    "Phone": "(612) 291-1000",
    "Fax": "(612) 291-2001",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitepremierbuy.com"
}, {
    "ID": 10,
    "CompanyName": "ElectrixMax",
    "Address": "263 Shuman Blvd",
    "City": "Naperville",
    "State": "Illinois",
    "Zipcode": 60563,
    "Phone": "(630) 438-7800",
    "Fax": "(630) 438-7801",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsiteelectrixmax.com"
}, {
    "ID": 11,
    "CompanyName": "Video Emporium",
    "Address": "1201 Elm Street",
    "City": "Dallas",
    "State": "Texas",
    "Zipcode": 75270,
    "Phone": "(214) 854-3000",
    "Fax": "(214) 854-3001",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitevideoemporium.com"
}, {
    "ID": 12,
    "CompanyName": "Screen Shop",
    "Address": "1000 Lowes Blvd",
    "City": "Mooresville",
    "State": "North Carolina",
    "Zipcode": 28117,
    "Phone": "(800) 445-6937",
    "Fax": "(800) 445-6938",
    "Website": "http://www.nowebsitescreenshop.com"
}];

@Injectable()
export class Service {
    getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Batch Edits**
If you want the user to edit multiple rows and then save all changes together, you can make use of the 'Batch Edit' feature in DevExtreme. [Official Documentaion](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/BatchEditing/Angular/Light/)
Add the `dxo-editing` tag as shown here

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="customers"
    [columns]="['CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax']">

        <dxo-editing 
            mode="batch"
            [allowUpdating]="true">
        </dxo-editing>

</dx-data-grid>
```

**Row by Row Edit**
If you want the user to only edit one row at a time, you can make use of the 'Row Edit' feature in DevExtreme. [Official Documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/Angular/Light/)
Add the `dxo-editing` tag as shown here

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="customers"
    [columns]="['CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax']">

        <dxo-editing 
            mode="row"
            [allowUpdating]="true">
        </dxo-editing>

</dx-data-grid>
```